# I have a 38mm apple watch and I put in on power reserve and no matter what I do it wont get out of it.

Tags: apple-watch

I have held the side button, I have held both buttons down. Each for 6 seconds or even to a minute nothing is working. Please help!

Comment: Did you try to charge your Apple Watch first?

Comment: yes I charged it all night

Answer (score 1):

To get out of Power Reserve, follow the instructions on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204608#powerreserve) page.

**To turn off Power Reserve:**

```
1. Press and hold the side button until you see the Apple logo.
2. Wait for your Apple Watch to restart. You might need to charge your Apple Watch first.
```

Comment: I've charged it and I hold the side button down for over 30 seconds, nothing happens